# изменить текст в созданном виджете

Tags: python, tkinter

Я создаю две вкладки через notebook с менами 'один', 'два'. А как после я могу программно изменить их название?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook
window = Tk()
window.size(800, 600)
tab_control = Notebook(window)
tab1 = Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab1, text='один')
tab_control.add(tab2, text='два')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вот так: `tab1.configure(text='new text')`

Comment: `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-text"`

Comment: window.size(800, 600) - это у вас не дает ошибки?

Comment: @splash58 возможно, по памяти писал, поробуюте вместо этого `window.geometry("500x350")`. Ваш способ не рабочий, как вы и убедились сами, ошибка что нет тако опции текст. странно вообще, я уже по всякому пробовал, до того как написать сюда.

Comment: `tab_control.tab(tab2, text = 'new text')`

Comment: @krolaper какой способ не рабочий, я вам позже вашего комментария послал "способ" :)

Comment: @splash58 странно, пробовал так же не работало, сейчас вбил заработало. Спасибо